# Не обновляется список RecyclerView после добавления элемента

Tags: java, android

В первом фрагменте заполняю List mItemList элементами из базы. Далее вывожу список элементов через RecyclerView на экране. Тут всё ок.

Вызываю второе активити с фрагментом через startActivityForResult() по нажатию на кнопку в первом фрагменте. Во втором фрагменте добавляю новый элемент в базу, устанавливаю результат и метод finish().

Далее в первом фрагменте получаю ответ в onActivityResult(), обновляю List mItemList (получаю новый список элементов), вызываю у адаптера RecyclerView метод .notifyDataSetChanged() но список на экране не обновляется.

```
    public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Item> mItemList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ItemListAdapter mItemListAdapter;
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

        mItemList = getItemList(); // Берет данные из базы

        mItemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), mItemList);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.hasFixedSize();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter);

        mFab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(ItemAddActivity.newIntent(getActivity()), 6);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 6) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
               mItemList = getItemList();

               // Проверяю что на самом деле List с item увеличился
               Log.d("MY_TEST", String.valueOf(mItemList.size()));

               // Обновляю адаптер, но список item'ов не обновляется на экране
                mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так похоже вы добавили его в базу, но не добавили элемент в коллекцию, которая была передана адаптеру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема вот тут:

```java
if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
    mItemList = getItemList(); // <- issue

    // Проверяю что на самом деле List с item увеличился
    Log.d("MY_TEST", String.valueOf(mItemList.size()));

    // Обновляю адаптер, но список item'ов не обновляется на экране
    mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

список в адаптере не изменится, потому что `mItemList` теперь будет указывать на новый список. Чтобы список и в адаптере изменился, нужно не изменять ссылку `mItemList`, а изменить данные в ней:

```java
if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
    mItemList.clear();
    mItemList.addAll(getItemList());

    // Проверяю что на самом деле List с item увеличился
    Log.d("MY_TEST", String.valueOf(mItemList.size()));

    // Обновляю адаптер, но список item'ов не обновляется на экране
    mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, шайтан машина заработала :)

Скажите, я правильно всё понял: 

1. Когда во фрагменте передаю mItemList через конструктор в адаптер, то в поле адаптера, хранится точно такая же ссылка на объект как и в mItemList?

2. И когда я добавляю новый элемент в базу и затем во фрагменте по новой делаю так mItemList = getItemList(), то у меня mItemList содержит новую ссылку на новый объект с List<Item>, но адаптер не обновляется потому что поле в адаптере, содержит старую ссылку на старый объект List<Item>?

Comment: @artur_mm Да, вы все правильно поняли